# Salesforce Function For Validation on Selection a value from Picklist

Tags: validation, validation-rule

What function should I use for validation rule as I want a validation rule to be used if I select a value from a picklist. for example, IsChanged can be used for updating the record. I cant use IsNew as Salesforce is giving an error that it cant be used with a picklist.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this way

```
TEXT( Status__c ) = 'Hired'
```

here Status__c is my picklist and Hired is one of the value for which I am checking error condition in my validation formula.

You can also do the same thing this way:

```
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Hired')
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNEW() in combination with a picklist field you should be able to do something like this:

```
ISPICKVAL(PicklistField, "Value") && ISNEW()
```

Which basically says error if the picklist field equals this value and the record is new.

> **ISNEW** Checks if the formula is running during the creation of a new
>   record and returns TRUE if it is. If an existing record is being
>   updated, this function returns FALSE.
>
> ```
> ISNEW()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ISBLANK with TEXT to check to see if the field has a value or not.

```
ISBLANK(TEXT(My_Field__c))
```

If you need to check to see if the picklist is a specific value, use ISPICKVAL

```
ISPICKVAL(My_Field__c, "Some Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

ISPICKVAL(Picklistvalue__c, "Some Value") && NOTISPICKVAL(Picklistvalue__c, "Some Value")